# авторизация instagram

Tags: python

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста. При валидном запросе, сервер отдаёт 200 ответ. Данные mid, ig_pr, ig_vw - статичные. При выполнении скрипта вылетает 200 ответ, но при изменении логина на неправильный, всё равно получаю 200 ответ

```
LOGIN = ""
PASSWORD = ""
session = requests.Session()
url = 'https://www.instagram.com/'



def parce(session, url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    result = re.search('"csrf_token": "(.+?)"', page.text)
    if result and len(result.group(1)) > 0:
        return result.group(1)
    else:
        print("unlucky")







def authLogin(LOGIN, PASSWORD, session, url):
    token = parce(session, url)
    payload = ("username=%s&password=%s") % (LOGIN, PASSWORD)
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Cookie': 'mid=VlcPHwAEAAEhgGWvu15J8g0GCsRK; ig_pr=1; ig_vw=1920; s_network=; csrftoken={0}'.format(token)}
    page = session.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)



authLogin(LOGIN, PASSWORD, session, url)
```

Comment: Так может оно всегда 200 выдаёт, анализируйте что в данных приходит

Comment: при невалидных данных сервер отдаёт 302

Comment: У Instagram вроде же  API есть?

Comment: Да есть, но интересно именно так написать